# Imagekit EACCES - Access denied by AWS S3. Check attached IAM policy on AWS

Tags: amazon-s3, encryption, amazon-kms, imagekit

After I set up Imagekit connecting to S3 bucket correctly with IAM policy having the `s3:GetObject` to the bucket, I got an error accessing the image through Imagekit url.

The error message is
`EACCES - Access denied by AWS S3. Check attached IAM policy on AWS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagekit actually needs more than just action `s3:GetObject` in the policy if your objects in the S3 buckets are server-side encrypted. It will `kms:Decrypt` as well. This is not in their documentation as 2022/06/16.

My IAM policy is like the following to make Imagekit access correctly.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "ImagekitObjectAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::[imagekit-bucket-name]/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "ImagekitObjectEncryptingKeyAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:187681360541:key/[object-encrypting-key-id]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```